# MS Word Spell Check

Tags: microsoft-word, authoring, grammar

Can anyone tell me how to suppress the 'Ignore Once' option in MS Word? I want any grammatical errors ignored totally not just once. I'm an author and use dialogue frequently. The spoken word is not like proper English so I have a continual fight with Spell Check

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the red underlines, then go to File > Options > Proofing. Then uncheck "Check spelling as you type" and "Mark grammar error as you type". Then click OK and you will not get the red lines any more and the grammatical errors will be ignored (Word 2016, will work in others versions also)

Comment: Just add some information for reference. For more information about Spelling and Grammar checker in Office, read these official articles: [Check grammar, spelling, and more in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-grammar-spelling-and-more-in-word-0f43bf32-ccde-40c5-b16a-c6a282c0d251) and [Check spelling and grammar in Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-spelling-and-grammar-in-Office-5cdeced7-d81d-47de-9096-efd0ee909227).